# Should tag(s) be added to a question because the tag(s) are applicable to the answers?

Tags: discussion, tags

I [just rolled back](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7586063/revisions) an edit on my question that added [java](/questions/tagged/java). The person who added the tag gave as reason that some answers are in Java. I personally think that if the answers are in Java this does not mean that the question should be tagged Java - and so I removed the tag.

Was I right?

Comment: *Usually* adding a tag based on the answers is correct, but in this case you made the right call.

Comment: If that question is based on pure math, I believe its off topic for SO.

Comment: @AbZy well it's quite a common problem in some areas (mostly games), with a __specific__ function made for it in most programming languages ([atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)). I think 27000+ views can't be ignored either.

Answer (score 4):

You were completely right on this. This has nothing to do with Java in particular. It is soley in general math, applicable for all languages.

Answer (score 0):

Tags are added to the question because the topic of the question, not because what said in answers.
Suppose there is a Drupal question asking which module should be used to achieve a specific task; different users would probably suggest different modules, but that doesn't mean the question should have a tag for each of the suggested modules, when those tags exists. (This example is for a possible question on *Drupal Answers*.)